Why doesn't the background color of a button inside a Popup change on IsMouseOver trigger?
I am creating custom buttons inside a Popup, and I’ve set a style with a trigger to change the button's background when the mouse hovers over it IsMouseOver. However, despite the style containing the trigger to change the background, the button does not change its color when the mouse hovers over it. I suspect that the Popup might be intercepting the mouse events and not passing them to the button.
I have set AllowsTransparency to true for the Popup, but this did not solve the issue. I need the buttons inside the Popup to correctly respond to the IsMouseOver event and change their background color.
Minimal Reproducible Example:
public static class ButtonStyles
{
    public static Style CreateCustomButtonStyle()
    {
        Style buttonStyle = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Button));
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.Button.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(51, 51, 51))));
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.Button.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(128, 0, 255))));
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.Button.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0)));
        buttonStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.Button.FontFamilyProperty, new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Arial Black")));

        buttonStyle.Triggers.Add(new Trigger
        {
            Property = System.Windows.Controls.Button.IsMouseOverProperty,
            Value = true,
            Setters =
            {
                new Setter(System.Windows.Controls.Button.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0)))
            }
        });

        return buttonStyle;
    }
}

private void ShowContextMenu()
{
    if (contextMenuPopup != null)
    {
        contextMenuPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }

    contextMenuPopup = new Popup
    {
        PlacementTarget = row,
        Placement = PlacementMode.MousePoint,
        StaysOpen = false,
        AllowsTransparency = true,
        Child = new StackPanel
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(51, 51, 51)),
            Width = 200,
            Children =
            {
                CreateContextButton("TEST1", () => TEST1_Click()),
                CreateContextButton("TEST2", () => TEST2_Click()),
                CreateContextButton("TEST3", () => TEST3_Click()),
                CreateContextButton("TEST4", () => TEST4_Click()),
                CreateContextButton("TEST5", () => TEST5_Click())
            }
        }
    };

    contextMenuPopup.IsOpen = true;
}

private System.Windows.Controls.Button CreateContextButton(string content, Action clickAction)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Button button = new System.Windows.Controls.Button
    {
        Content = content,
        Style = ButtonStyles.CreateCustomButtonStyle(),
        Width = 200,
        Height = 25
    };
    button.Click += (sender, e) => clickAction();
    return button;
}

